# When to quote a macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

In SAS, while referencing a macro variable, I see that sometimes the code uses double quotes around the macro reference, but other times, it reference the variable without the quotes.

When should I use quotes before my & and when should I not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to quote macro variables when you are using them in place of hard-coded non-macro-text that would normally need to be quoted - usually in proc or data step code, e.g.

```
%let text = Hello;

/*You need quotes here*/
data _null_;
put "&text";
run;

/*Otherwise you get an error, because SAS thinks hello is a variable name*/
data _null_;
put &text;
run;

/*If you already have quotes in your macro var, you don't need to include them again in the data step code*/
%let text2 = "Hello";
data _null_;
 put &text2;
run;

/*In macro statements, everything is already treated as text, so you don't need the quotes*/
%put &text;

/*If you include the quotes anyway, they are counted as part of the text for macro purposes*/
%put "&text";


/*When you are calling functions via %sysfunc that normally
require a variable name or a quoted string, you don't need quotes*/
%let emptyvar=;
%put %sysfunc(coalescec(&emptyvar,&text));
```

Comment: Good answer.  You might want to add an example of `%sysfunc` to that, that's a common mistake.